# Failed authentification requests (401 Unauthorized) from mirage always resolves in ember-simple-auth-token

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth, ember-cli-mirage

In my Ember app, I have an action for login.

```
login: function(emailAddress, password) {
  this.get('session').authenticate('authenticator:jwt', {
      'identification': emailAddress,
      'password': password
  }).catch((reason) => {
      console.log('Reason: ' + JSON.stringify(reason));
      this.set('errorMessage', 'Login failed.');
  });
}
```

When I test with my server (http://127.0.0.1:8091), it works fine. When the response is 200, I'm logged in. If it's 401, my error message is set.

The problem happens with ember-cli-mirage. I have this code for testing:

```
this.post('http://127.0.0.1:8091', function(db, req) {
  let body = JSON.parse(req.requestBody);
  if (body.handler === 'test@example.com!' && body.password === 'secretpassword') {
    return {
      token: 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6ImFiYzEyMyJ9.X0O3xMVikn-5l9gXBU5a2XF6vlMmTzm4mCqUNA68e-A',
      id: 'abc123'
    };
  } else {
    return new Response(401, {}, {});
  }
});
```

I just send a testing token and it works when the credentials are correct. I can log in into my app. But if I try with wrong credentials, then I get this error in my JS console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

After a little bit of investigation, it seems the error happens inside the function getTokenData which is called in this piece of code:

```
authenticate: function authenticate(credentials, headers) {
  var _this2 = this;

  return new _ember['default'].RSVP.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var data = _this2.getAuthenticateData(credentials);

    _this2.makeRequest(_this2.serverTokenEndpoint, data, headers).then(function (response) {
      _ember['default'].run(function () {
        var token = _ember['default'].get(response, _this2.tokenPropertyName);
        var tokenData = _this2.getTokenData(token);
        var expiresAt = _ember['default'].get(tokenData, _this2.tokenExpireName);
        var tokenExpireData = {};

        _this2.scheduleAccessTokenRefresh(expiresAt, token);

        tokenExpireData[_this2.tokenExpireName] = expiresAt;

        response = _ember['default'].merge(response, tokenExpireData);

        resolve(_this2.getResponseData(response));
      });
    }, function (xhr) {
      _ember['default'].run(function () {
        reject(xhr.responseJSON || xhr.responseText);
      });
    });
  });
},
```

See the line where it says `var tokenData = _this2.getTokenData(token);`. Shouldn't the second function (rejected promise) be called since the request was rejected?

It looks like ember-simple-auth-token is trying to work with a token that doesn't exist since the response was an empty 401. I tried including a token even in the rejected request, but I still get the same error.

Remember that when the response comes from my local server (and even my real server), it works fine.

I couldn't find a way to debug mirage. How can I see the details about the responses? Requests don't appear under the Network tab in my Developer Tools from my browser.

What next should I look into to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Mirage.Response` instead of `Response` solved the issue. By using `Response`, the response itself was empty (`{}`) so mirage would make it an empty 200 OK by default.